# Speed up N(P) problem search - Sum-Square Problem

Tags: c#, math, iteration, np

Speed up N(P) problem search - Sum-Square Problem

I was wondering if anyone could help me figuring out ways to speed up a small programm I was working on.
The problem is a math exercise called the Sum-Square Problem (https://youtu.be/G1m7goLCJDY).
So you take a list of continuous integers starting at 1 to N and see if you can reorder them so that the sum of each pair makes a square.
So for example:

1-3-6-10-15-
or
1-15-10-6-3-13-12-4-5-11-14-2-7-9-

The trick is to use all the numbers in the domain [1,N]. Obviously you can either find just one solution proving that there is a solution for [1,N] or you can show all the solutions for that domain. In the latter case you will get a reverse solution for each solution obviously, plus you can get so-called cyclic solutions where the start and end also make a square.
Now increasing N (after 23 there seems to be a solution for each N - not proven) exponentially increases the number of possible branches or paths you can try.

My program first was simple loops which checked basically every option. This meant my computer (simple i9 core) started to struggle (processing > 1h) at around N=30. I then changed method and first created a table or matrix containing only those numbers that would create a square for each number [1,N]. So for N=15 (first possible N with a solution) you would get:
For N=15 the squares possible are: 4, 9, 16, 25

1 - 3, 8, 15
2 - 7, 14
3 - 1, 6, 13
....
15 - 1, 10

I then traversed through this table to find possible solutions. If a path dead-ended the program backtracks until there is anpther branch, tries that one, backtracks, etc.
This took me up to about N=50 before it started taking too long (>1h) for my taste. 
Up til then I was working with Lists (using C#) so I tried HashSets, that took it up to about N = 70. Now I seem to be stuck.
I either:
1) have to find another function that can process running through lists and paths faster, or
2) think of a completely different approach in mathematically solving this
3) step up the processing power

Does anyone have a smarter suggestion then the ones I thought of myself?
My code (C#):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SumSquare
{
    public class CalculateHash
    {
        List<List<int>> matrix = new List<List<int>>();
        List<int> squares = new List<int>();
        List<int> branch = new List<int>();
        HashSet<int> defaultList = new HashSet<int>();
        HashSet<int> worklist = new HashSet<int>();
        int currentN, currentSet, currentIndex; //, prevIndex;
        int max;
        List<int> prevIndexSet = new List<int>(); //Holds prevSet index
        bool going, going2;
        DateTime startTime;
        int successes = 0;
        int cyclic = 0;
        TimeSpan elapsed;

        public void Calculate(int maxNum)
        {
            max = maxNum;
            squares = FillSquares(max);
            matrix = CreateMatrix(squares, max);
            startTime = DateTime.Now;
            for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
            {
                branch.Clear();
                worklist.Clear();
                branch.Add(i);
                worklist = FillDefaultList(max);//Fill with all but current start number
                worklist.Remove(i);
                currentIndex = 0;
                currentN = matrix[i][0]; //Get first element
                currentSet = i; //remember current set, starting number
                going = true;
                while (going)
                {
                    if (worklist.Contains(currentN))//Is this number still available?
                    {
                        branch.Add(currentN); //add currentN
                        worklist.Remove(currentN);//Clean up worklist
                        if (worklist.Count == 0) //All numbers processed! HIT
                        {
                            successes++;
                            ShowSucces();
                            //to quit at the first success
                            //going = false; //Quit at first success
                            //i = max + 1; //quit programm
                        }
                        prevIndexSet.Add(currentIndex);
                        currentSet = currentN;
                        currentN = matrix[currentSet][0];
                        currentIndex = 0;//reset for next Set
                    }
                    else //number already in use!
                    {
                        currentIndex++;
                        going2 = true;
                        if (currentIndex == matrix[currentSet].Count) //Used up all the numbers in this set?
                        {
                            while (going2)
                            {
                                int prevSet = branch[branch.Count - 1];//get the last number added at which this branch halted
                                branch.RemoveAt(branch.Count - 1); //remove this last number
                                //We need to add the number prevSet back into the workList BUT
                                //it needs to go at the correct location!! To keep the numbers in order
                                worklist.Add(prevSet); //Add the number back
                                if (branch.Count == 0) //We've exhausted all the possible paths starting with number (i)
                                {
                                    going2 = false; //break out if this while
                                    going = false; //break out of parent while
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    currentSet = branch[branch.Count - 1]; //Get the last number of the previous set
                                    currentIndex = prevIndexSet[prevIndexSet.Count - 1] + 1; //Get the position in that set whee we last stopped and get the next position
                                    prevIndexSet.RemoveAt(prevIndexSet.Count - 1);//remove that index reference
                                    if (currentIndex < matrix[currentSet].Count) //No more numbers in this set
                                    {
                                        currentN = matrix[currentSet][currentIndex]; //carry on
                                        going2 = false;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            currentN = matrix[currentSet][currentIndex]; //Get the next number in this Set
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            TimeSpan elapsedTime = DateTime.Now - startTime;
            Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: " + elapsedTime.TotalSeconds);
            Console.WriteLine("Number of successes: " + (successes * 0.5));
            Console.WriteLine("Number of cyclic successes: " + cyclic);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        List<List<int>> CreateMatrix(List<int> s, int m)
        {
            //This creates a 2-dimensional List, First dimension is [1,max], Second dimension the number need to get a sum when added to the current number
            List<List<int>> t = new List<List<int>>();
            t.Add(new List<int>()); //Element 0 is empty
            for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
            {
                List<int> tt = new List<int>();
                for (int j = 0; j < s.Count; j++)
                {
                    int difference = s[j] - i;
                    if ((difference > 0) && (difference <= max) && difference != i) //Needs to be >0 and <=max
                    {
                        tt.Add(s[j] - i); //Now add the result: Square - currentINT
                    }
                }
                t.Add(tt); //Now stuff it into the parent List where INT=1 is Index=0
            }
            return t;
        }

        HashSet<int> FillDefaultList(int maxInt) //Fills a List with [1,max] integers
        {
            HashSet<int> l = new HashSet<int>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
            {
                l.Add(i);
            }
            return l;
        }

        List<int> FillSquares(int max) //Creates a list of the squares of all values from [2,max] below the max + max-1 sum
        {
            List<int> l = new List<int>();
            int maxSum = max + (max - 1);
            for (int i = 2; i < max; i++)
            {
                if ((i * i) <= maxSum)
                {
                    l.Add(i * i);
                }
            }
            return l;
        }

        List<int> RemoveElement(List<int> list, int number)
        {
            List<int> l = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                if (list[i] != number)
                {
                    l.Add(list[i]);
                }
            }
            return l;
        }

        HashSet<int> FillWorklist(HashSet<int> defList, int cNum)
        {
            HashSet<int> l = defList;
            l.Remove(cNum);
            return l;
        }

        void ShowSucces()
        {
            Console.Write("Found a path with starting number: " + branch[0]);
            if (squares.Contains(branch[0] + branch[branch.Count - 1])) //Is it cyclic?
            {
                cyclic++;
                Console.WriteLine(" - This branch is cyclic! ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < max - 1; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(branch[i] + ",");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(branch[max - 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be better suited for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Let numbers (`1`, `2`, `3`...) be *vertexes* which are connected by *edge* if and only if the sum is a *square* (i.e. `4` and `45` are connected since `4 + 45 == 49 == 7**2` when `3` and `8` are not connected: `3 + 8 == 11` - not a square). So the initial task is a Hamiltonian Path Problem and you can try solving it with existing solvers. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindHamiltonianPath.html

Comment: @Martin Wiboe: Thanks! I checked it and they primarily discuss if this is a true N(P) problem and not so much smart programming solutions.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko: Yes ofc you're correct. It is a special case of finding an Hamiltonian path. However as far as I know you can only solve this by brute force (and some smart avoiding using too much force). The question however remains: how to approach such a brute force with the least force - ie. the fastest processing?